# FullCalendar Not Updating After Event Creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) on one of my pages and the events are being populated from a database I have.

I am creating Events pretty basically:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,StartDate,EndDate,DescriptionId,AllDay")] Event @event)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Events.Add(@event);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
    }

    return View(@event);
}
```

When I am redirected to the `Index` page on the `Main` controller, the event I just created isn't showing up on the calendar.

Here is my `Index` action:

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    private DbContextName db = new DbContextName();
    // GET: Main
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = db.Events.ToList();
        return View(data);
    }

    // more code not related to the question
}
```

Here is how I'm populating my calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    themesystem: 'bootstrap-yeti',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    allDay:true,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: false,
    print: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: submissionUrl,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                var events = [];

                $.each(result,
                    function(i, data) {

                        events.push({
                            title: data.Title,
                            description: data.Description,
                            start: moment(data.Start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                            end: moment(data.End).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                            color: data.Color
                        });
                    });

                callback(events);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    },
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description);
    }
});
```

After I create a new event, and redirected to the Index page, I check the console I see all of the events except the one I just created.. but if I refresh the page, then the event appears and everything is okay.  But, why isn't it doing that on the redirect?

**UPDATE**

`submissionUrl` goes to a method called `GetCalendarData` on my `Main` controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCalendarData()
{
    var data =
        db.Events.Select(
            x =>
                new
                {
                    Title = x.Title,
                    Description = x.Description.DescriptionTitle,
                    Start = x.StartDate,
                    End = x.EndDate,
                    Color = x.Description.Color
                }).ToList();

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: When you say you see it in the console, you mean that on the network tab it isn't being returned from the server? It could be a caching issue. Make sure that the request in the console that contains the events doesn't have an HTTP code 304 on it.

Comment: Well when I'm debugging, I put a breakpoint on the `GetCalendarData` action.. and when I'm redirected after creating an event, that breakpoint is never hit.. but when I refresh the page.. the breakpoint is hit

Comment: Nope, not 304 in console.

Comment: @kettch I just got it to work, I had the script you see in my question in a separate js file and referenced that js file in my Bundle.config and referenced that bundle in my `_Layout` page.. but now I just copied the js above to be directly on the `Index` page and it worked.  Any reason why I can't have this in a separate file?

Comment: @kettch actually, nevermind.. for some reason it's not showing up again.. no matter where the script is...

Comment: Any reason why you are pushing all of the events to a local collection instead of hooking the `events` property of fullcalendar directly up to your service? It's not necessarily related, but it would simplify your definition greatly.

Comment: @kettch could you display what you mean?

Comment: @GTown-Colder I added an answer with an example, but I want to make sure I understand your workflow. A user goes to an "Add Event" view, fills out a form, and clicks "submit", then they are redirected to a page with the fullcalendar control that is then initialized? If this is a full postback, I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't get the full data every time. The issue could be in your code that converts the JSON data to events.

Comment: @kettch It is a full postback, which is why this is confusing me so much..

Comment: I'm still concerned that there might be caching going on here.

Comment: @kettch How do I delete all cache after postback?

Comment: @kettch tested in Chrome and it works as expected everytime.. just not in IE 11

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try adding `cache: false` to your inner ajax call. This will have jquery try to avoid getting cached data.

**For future consideration**

Since it appears that you have an API service that returns something very close to what fullcalendar is looking for, you might be able to simplify the way your definition populates events.

```
let eventUrl = 'http://myserver/myapp/mycontroller/geteventjson';

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                themesystem: 'bootstrap-yeti',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
                },
                allDay: true,
                navLinks: true, 
                editable: false,
                print: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                events: eventUrl, // Simply a url that returns JSON events
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm', 
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description);
                }
            });
```

Full calendar can populate itself straight from your service, without needing a local collection.